# How do I make WinEdt show the TOC (Table of Contents)?

Tags: winedt

How do I make WinEdt show the TOC (Table of Contents) used for navigation? Similar to the TOC visible in the image below (source: [WinEdt Snapshots](http://www.winedt.com/snap.html)):

[image]

Comment: I’m quite sure, that WinEdt doesn’t show the TOC, which needed to created first, but searches itself for heading entries like `\chapter`, `\section` and so on.

Comment: I've inserted an image to clarify what you're talking about/referring to. Please let roll back to the previous version if this is not clear/incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click in menu "View" the entry "tree". This will open the tree panel. To update it click in the panel on the left icon (build tree). This will build the tree of the main file (if there is a main file) or of the current active document.

To set a main file click on the small document with the + on the left of the second icon row. To remove the "main file status" click on the small document with the -.  You can see the name of the current main file (if there is one) on the right in the status line at the bottom.

Comment: I am wondering is there a way to automatically update/build tree when there are some changed made to the tex file.